Objects in error response can't be parsed by Swagger UI
In my fastapi app I decided to handle all errors in a middleware:
class HandleErrors(BaseHTTPMiddleware):
    """
    Handle all possible exceptions.
    The reason we do this in a middleware is that we want to make sure all middleware are executed,
    even when an exception is raised, which is not possible with the usual exception handlers.

    This also ensures exception information is passed down the stack via `request.state`.
    """

    async def dispatch(self, request: Request, call_next: RequestResponseEndpoint) -> Response:
        try:
            return await call_next(request)
        except RequestValidationError as req_err:
            request.state.exc = req_err
            error_detail = jsonable_encoder(req_err.errors())
            status_code = status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY
        except StarletteHTTPException as http_err:
            request.state.exc = http_err
            error_detail = http_err.detail
            status_code = http_err.status_code
        except Exception as err:
            request.state.exc = err
            error_detail = {"detail": jsonable_encoder("500 - Internal Server Error")}
            status_code = status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
        return JSONResponse(status_code=status_code, content={"data": None, "error": error_detail, "pagination": None}, headers=getattr(request.state.exc, "headers", None))

The JSONResponse's content that is returned has that shape because of another design decision: standardizing all json responses to always have the same properties no matter what.
This works mostly fine, however the Swagger UI doesn't seem to like it. For example, when clicking the authorize button in the /docs endpoint and doing something that raises a RequestValidationError (for example submitting an empty password field), this is the result:

Please note that RequestValidationErrors by default has a list of dicts as its content (see https://github.com/fastapi/fastapi/blob/master/fastapi/exception_handlers.py), so it's not some custom error that I created that does not conform to the standard, and it feels strange that fastapi uses Swagger UI when the latter can't properly consume the former's error responses.
Interestingly, if my API returns a 200 code, Swagger does manage recognize that there's been an error and parse the error array:

I have identified the relevant swagger code here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/src/core/plugins/auth/actions.js
If the status code is 200, line #205 is executed and since we have a non-null error property, Swagger correctly identifies the authorization failed and, since response.ok is true, the error is stringified:
    let token = JSON.parse(response.data)
    let error = token && ( token.error || "" )
    let parseError = token && ( token.parseError || "" )

    if ( !response.ok ) {
      errActions.newAuthErr( {
        authId: name,
        level: "error",
        source: "auth",
        message: response.statusText
      } )
      return
    }

    if ( error || parseError ) {
      errActions.newAuthErr({
        authId: name,
        level: "error",
        source: "auth",
        message: JSON.stringify(token)
      })
      return
    }

However, when status code is an error one (like 422), we go straight to the catch block at #232, and there no stringification happens.
So I have two questions:

What is the best way to work around this? And by "best" I mean the way with the least amount of code and customization, which pretty much rules out customizing swagger-ui-bundle.js? Should I simply create an AuthorizationException in my authorization endpoint and give it special treatment in the middleware?

Is this worth raising an issue for? If so, where? With fastapi or swagger-ui?


